# How to get http headers in OpenFire API

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I'm using openfire as XMPP server. Clients connect to it via BOSH. 
I'm writing some plugin with custom iq's, and I need to get my clients' http headers.
 How can I do this using Openfire API?

Comment: This seems like a pretty serious layer violation.  Can you explain more about the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to retrieve X-Real-Ip header with visitor's IP that is set by my proxy (nginx) and I don't know how to do it in my custom openfire plugin. I'd also prefer to get User-Agent Referer and Cookies directly from headers and not to set it as iq nodes via javascript.

Comment: Just a little more info... *Why* do you want the IP address?  Perhaps there's a more elegant solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: I need to provide IP address and geo location of visitors to my support team (folks in the support team also connected to XMPP server)

Comment: you could try asking this on the openfire forums, or using their developer chat. I found them useful when writing plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was digging this myself some time ago and found nothing, so I think the best solution is to wrap some user info that you want to get via headers into XMPP iq's (User-Agent, Referrer, ...).
To get visitor's IP you can also use Openfire API (look at SessionManager class).

Comment: yes, thanks! my biggest problem was visitor's IP, but I can use SessionManager.getInstance().getSession(visitorJid).getHostAddress()